# Find Occurrence then find next Occurrence from a segment in the first result

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, logs

I am looking for a little help, I am learning as I go. I have something similar to the following below. I am looking to display the occurrence of **"Logged in"** on Log1, and then the **"Processed Bill"** on Log1. Using the search value of - 44. This honestly looks like I am trying to cheat a test or something, but its not, I am new to breaking files down, and looking to learn.

file.txt

```
Log0 | 20191104 | 01 | Logged In - 55
Log1 | 20191104 | 04 | Logged In - 44
Log2 | 20191104 | 03 | Logged In - 33
Log1 | 20191104 | 02 | Received Bill
Log1 | 20191104 | 02 | Accepted Bill
Log2 | 20191104 | 05 | Logged Out - 33
Log1 | 20191104 | 33 | Processed Bill
Log0 | 20191104 | 44 | Broken Bill
```

Looking for desired output.

```
Log1 | 20191104 | 04 | Logged In - 44
Log1 | 20191104 | 33 | Processed Bill
```

Comment: What connects 44 with "Processed Bill"?

Comment: log1 would be the key

Comment: So you don't know it's `Log1` you're looking for, you just want to find the `Logged In` with the `- 44` and the corresponding `Processed Bill` with the same value in the first column?

Comment: yes exactly. Log1 could be anything, but it would be the same value for both the logged in and the processed bill. But would have to search upon the 44 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact very similar to @Choroba solution:

```
awk -F'|'   '/Logged In/                   { login[$1]=$0}     
             /Processed Bill/ && login[$1] { print login[$1]; print}' ex1
```

Where:

- `/Logged In/ { login[$1]=$0}` -- saves the lines with "Logged in" associated to column 1 (ex "Log1")
- `/Processed Bil/ && login[$1] {print ...}` -- prints when it finds a "Processed Bill" previously login

Correction: To print just 44:

```
awk -F'|'   '/Logged In - 44/              { cod=$1; line=$0}     
             /Processed Bill/ && $1==cod   { print line "\n" $0}' file
```

Comment: And what about the `- 44` (assuming there may be other pairs of `Logged In` and `Processed Bill` that they _don't_ want to see)?

Comment: @Kusalananda, You are right. Although already in the initial PO statement, the clarifying explanations comments appeared after my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -F'/\|/' -ne '$id = $F[0] if $F[3] =~ /- 44$/;
                   print if $F[0] eq $id && $F[3] =~ /Logged In|Processed Bill/;
                  ' -- file.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-F` splits each input line on the given regex into the `@F` array
- if `$F[3]`, i.e. the fourth column, matches `- 44`, the first column is stored in `$id`.
- the whole line is printed if the first column equals the `$id` and the fourth column matches `Logged In` or `Processed Bill`.

Answer (score 0):

With Gnu sed in extended regex mode:

```
$ sed -re ':a
    /Logged In - 44/!d
    $d;h;N
    /^(\S+)\s*\|.*\n\1\s*\|.*Processed Bill/b
    g;ba
' file
```

**Results**

```
Log1 | 20191104 | 04 | Logged In - 44
Log1 | 20191104 | 33 | Processed Bill
```

**How it works**

```
° Skip lines till we meet "Logged In 44"
° Pick up the nexr line and if it is "Processed Bill" AND first field matches with the logged in line, then it's a GO.
° Otherwise, discard the second portion and redo this process. 
° Assumption is that logged in 44 line is unique.
```

Comment: This one was very interesting, if you had to, how would you combined fields 1 and 2 as the key?

Comment: Then change the regex to this: `/^(([^|]+[|]){2}).*\n\1.*Processed Bill/b`

Comment: That is so interesting, this is very helpful. Sorry if I want to challenge more, but what if in the same file, Logged In - 44 and Processed Bill appears again, and I would want to display the additional occurrences, is this possible in sed?

Comment: Can you provide the input and the expected output for this scenario?